# Skip one line code if the tuple list count is 0

Tags: python, tuples

I am running an SQL query in order to bring some values looking at a tuple list . But there are situations where there are no values in the tuple because there are no values in the database . Due to that my code is stopped because the query can't be runned with no values in the tuple.

Is there a way i can skip the next line whenever the tuple count is <1?

Thanks a lot in advance !
:)

I have tried to remove the null values but it doesn't work and i can't find anything to help me to skip one line.

Thanks a lot again!

Comment: `if len(values) > 0: code that does the query else: do something else by default`

Comment: Can you post a sample code snippet so that it's clearer to those who read your question?